# How can I find how many database calls Entity Framework is making per incoming request?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am running a C# 4.0 website that uses Entity Framework 4.0 for database interaction.  I want to find the pages that are causing Entity Framework to make the most calls to the database (since the more calls, the slower the page is likely to be).

I'd add some sort of instrumentation to Entity Framework, have actual users operate the website for a while, then analyze some sort of log to find out what pages generated the most calls to the database.

Is there some kind of performance counter or other event that can be inspected to figure out when a database call has been made by Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try the [Entity Framework Profiler](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/Entity-Framework-Profiler) (its own site is [here](http://efprof.com/)), although this is not a free product, it does however have a 30 day free trial.  And its written by [one of the smartest guys around](http://ayende.com/blog/)

It will however flag up issues, such as Select N+1 issues and warn you about bad practices.

From the blurb:

> Entity Framework Profiler is a
>   real-time visual debugger allowing a
>   development team to gain valuable
>   insight and perspective into their
>   usage of Entity Framework. The product
>   is architected with input coming from
>   many top industry leaders within the
>   OR/M community. Alerts are presented
>   in a concise code-review manner
>   indicating patterns of misuse by your
>   application. To streamline your
>   efforts to correct the misuse, we
>   provide links to the problematic code
>   section that triggered the alert

again from the blurb (in response to the comment):

> Using the Entity Framework Profiler is
>   easy. First, we need to make the
>   application that we profile aware of
>   the profiler. Then, just start the
>   profiler.
>
> Preparing an application to be
>   profiled
>
> Add a reference to the
>   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll
>   assembly, located in the downloadable
>   zip. In the application startup
>   (Application_Start in web
>   applications, Program.Main in Windows
>   / console applications, or the App
>   constructor for WPF applications),
>   make the following call:

```
HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize();
```

**EDIT**

seems that you can initialize the profiler for offline profiling.  use this to initialize it instead (from [here](http://efprof.com/Learn/Usage/OfflineProfiling)):

```
HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.InitializeOfflineProfiling(filename);
```

then load the resulting file into the profiler.

This seems like it should give you what you want.

Comment: interesting, but how does Entity Framework profiler accomplish its instrumentation?  That's really the important part to me.

Comment: updated with some info from the site.  it seems that it is a live thing, so you can see what is happening as people are using your site.  this tool will advise you of bad practices it detects which will likely help you establish where the issues are.

Comment: @Mike added the info about how you can use it to do profiling in an offline way, so you could do what you want and let your users use the site for a while then review where the issues are.

Answer (score 2):

Just start using server side sql-tracing. You can see exactly what the sql server is working through without adding overhead to the client.

Here is more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: sure, but that's a lot of manual work.  I'd prefer to add some instrumentation, let people use the website for a while, and then look at the results later.  With using the tracing I wouldn't be able to distinguish calls that belong to one page from those that belong to another either.

Comment: Please clearify the question that you're looking for a 'after the fact' analyser that should go through multiple Asp.Net pages and find which queries are the heaviest.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is a profiler, to count SQL calls only you could just use the built-in SQL profiler (not included in SQL Express though).

Answer (score 1):

For EF6, you can use `context.Database.Log`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx